# Is this possible with Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Below i am trying to pass in a list of ints to return all  products with a productID == to each int.

```
 public IQueryable<Product> GetProductsForSubCat(List<int> prodSubResult)
        {

            if (prodSubResult != null)
            {
                var _db = new ProductContext();

                IQueryable<Product> query = _db.Products;

                foreach (int x in prodSubResult)
                {
                     query = _db.Products.Where(p => p.ProductID == x);



                }
                    return query;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If the list has more than one element it should always return an empty collection

Comment: You should know by now, anything is possible with LINQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, and it's pretty straight forward:

```
var query = _db.Products.Where(p => prodSubResult.Contains(p.ProductId));
```

Comment: This is correct, provided the OP isn't looking for an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Product>>` to be returned.  Probably not, but it's unclear enough to be a possibility.

Comment: @Bobson Yeah, I just based my answer on the description of what the OP wanted, not the provided implementation (which has other flaws in it).

Comment: What are the flaws of doing it this way?

Comment: @jackncoke I'm not sure what flaws you mean. This is essentially equivalent to the SQL `WHERE ProductId IN ( ... )`. `query` contains all `Products` with a `ProductId` that is in the provided list of ID's.

Comment: Sorry maybe i miss read your comment. Thank you for your help!